# grails 3 cache - ehcache configuration

Tags: grails, ehcache, grails-3.1

I use Grails 3.1.8.
How can I set **timeToLiveSeconds** property?

plugin configuration [suggests me](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/guide/usage.html) to set:

```
grails.cache.config = {
   cache {
      …
   }
   defaultCache {
      maxElementsInMemory 10000
      eternal false
      timeToIdleSeconds 120
      timeToLiveSeconds 120
      overflowToDisk true
      maxElementsOnDisk 10000000
      diskPersistent false
      diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds 120
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy 'LRU'
   }
}
```

But that does not work for me. How can I set **default and custom** properties?

Answer (score 0):

The same document you link contains that information in the sections just before and after the ones you extracted that config sample from.

In the *Caches* section, for per cache config elements:

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
        name 'mycache'
        eternal false
        overflowToDisk true
        maxElementsInMemory 10000
        maxElementsOnDisk 10000000
    }
}
```

And in the second half of *Default cache and cache defaults*, for defaults:

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
        …
    }
    defaults {
        maxElementsInMemory 1000
        eternal false
        overflowToDisk false
        maxElementsOnDisk 0
    }
}
```

which will both accept the setting of `timeToLiveSeconds` property, as they are just examples and not an indication of configuration being limited to a restricted set of properties.

Answer (score 0):

According to [grails-cache-ehcache](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-ehcache) github you need [version 3](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/cache-ehcache) of the plugin for Grails 3 and according to it's [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/latest/#_configuration) only [XML configuration](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/xml.html) is supported now.

You can find an example in [issue#37](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-ehcache/issues/37).